# Angular 4 file naming conventions

Tags: angular, naming-conventions

I'm moving from AngularJS to Angular4 and the examples I have seen follow a naming convention. I am discussing Components mainly.
It appears to be the convention to have a app/components folder and then a separate folder underneath that for every component. That seems reasonable. But then in the examples I have seen for the component "mine" the filenames are mine.component.html, mine.component.ts and mine.component.css

Is there a good reason for this? The fact that it is under the components folder would seem to make the use of the .component portion irrelevant.

Further, if I have a component that itself contains components and those components are only ever to be used by that component, does it make sense to put them under app/components. Wouldn't it make more sense to put them in app/components/mine?

Generally i tend to follow the patterns I have observed because I figure that there is generally a good reason for it but I can't see any particular reason for these conventions.

Please set me straight.

Answer (score 4):

What I have seen by use of the Angular CLI, which claims "*It already follows our best practices!*", is that every component receives it's own folder inside of the same folder where you store your primary `AppModule`.

However, as you mentioned, with nesting folders, I've seen that as a practice too, but not necessarily with nesting components. Instead of putting components into components you would put components into modules.

Below is a sample directory...

```
    └── src
        └── app
           ├── module-one
           │  ├── component-one
           │  │  ├── component-one.component.html
           │  │  └── component-one.component.ts
           │  ├── component-two
           │  │  ├── component-two.component.html
           │  │  └── component-two.component.ts
           │  └── module-one.module.ts
           ├── module-two
           │  ├── component-three
           │  │  ├── component-three.component.html
           │  │  └── component-three.component.ts
           │  ├── component-four
           │  │  ├── component-four.component.html
           │  │  └── component-four.component.ts
           │  └── module-two.module.ts
           ├── app-routing.module.ts
           ├── app.component.html
           ├── app.component.ts
           └── app.module.ts
```

Comment: I will add that by default when you create a new component it gets added to the `AppModule` unless specified into a module.

Comment: If you also read the style guide it goes over all of these questions. Depending on the size of your application you may need to break the style guide rules to really make it easier for development and maintenance. 

Try reading about core and shared module and understand their use cases. As well depending on the complexity of your app, try giving your components used for routes specific names ( such as scene ) This helps quickly understand the purpose of those components over others.